# Define WHERE clause while update in Nhibernate

Tags: .net, nhibernate

Every table in my database has IsDeleted column. I don't want to update already deleted rows. When user updates some row I would like to add additional WHERE clause. So my SQL statement will look like this:

```
UPDATE ... WHERE Id=1 AND IsDeleted=0
```

This way I will eliminate situation when row is deleted in one transaction and got updated in another.

> ```
> First transaction             Second transaction
>
> Begin transaction             Begin transaction
> Read entity1 (IsDeleted==0)   Read entity1 (IsDeleted==0)
> Update entity1.IsDeleted=1    
> Commit
>                               Update entity1.Name="new name" 
>                               (should update 0 rows!!!)
> ```

I need a way to do it using some common NHibernate approach like Interceptor or Listener or some other NH feature.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would map the IsDeleted column and when I selected the initial entities to modify I would exclude where IsDeleted = 1.  I would then do my updates normally.

Generally you should update nhibernate entities by their primary keys and not do mass updates.

Comment: The problem is when second transaction reads entity1 then entity1.IsDeleted is equal 0 so there is no way to exclude by IsDeleted=1. I've update the question to make it more clear. By the way, I don't do mass updates. It's only for one entity.

Comment: To me the problem is your updating a single entity `entity1.Name="new name"` but it actually points to multiple records in the database.  It sounds like you need to add IsDeleted as part of the primary key (composite key) in nhibernate.  Also I'm not sure how entity1.IsDeleted would be 1 in the 2nd transaction since it had already been updated in transaction 1.

Comment: I described workflow in pseudo-code for simplicity. Saying "UPDATE entity1.Name="new name"" I mean "Update Entity SET name='new name' WHERE id=1".    entity1.IsDeleted will be 0 (not 1) in the second transaction until first transaction commits changes. My transaction isolation level is read committed.